# error when executing DUMP command in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

```
grunt> a = load '/cleartrip/prodqueue_cleartrip-quick-Nov05th14-morning.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS                                   
>> (col0:chararray, col1:chararray, col2:chararray, col3:chararray, col4:chararray, col5:chararray, col6:chararray, col7:chararray); 
grunt> b = limit a 10;
grunt> dump b;
```

```
Input(s):
Failed to read data from "/cleartrip/prodqueue_cleartrip-quick-Nov05th14-morning.txt"

Output(s):

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
null    ->  null,
null
```

Comment: its clearly saying Failed to read data from "/cleartrip/prodqueue_cleartrip-quick-Nov05th14-morning.txt". try to hadoop fs -ls Failed to read data from "/cleartrip/prodqueue_cleartrip-quick-Nov05th14-morning.txt"

Comment: subha sankar is right, seems like the file you are trying to read does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to Copy ur Sample.txt to Home Folder..It might help you clearly
then get into the pig in Hadoop
or better do one thing

Run Pig in local file system

Pig -x local